Products in woocommerce not working after implementing custom slug
I want to change woocommerce standard product permalink structure from /product/parent-category/category/product-slug to /parent-category/product-slug .
That's my functions.php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_post_type_link_parent_category_only', '__return_true');
function na_remove_slug($post_link, $post, $leavename)
{
    if ('product' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    $post_link = str_replace('/product/', '/', $post_link);
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3);
function change_slug_struct($query)
{
    if (! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count($query->query) || ! isset($query->query['page'])) {
        return;
    }
    if (! empty($query->query['name'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'product', 'page'));
    } elseif (! empty($query->query['pagename']) && false === strpos($query->query['pagename'], '/')) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'product', 'page'));
        // We also need to set the name query var since redirect_guess_404_permalink() relies on it.
        $query->set('name', $query->query['pagename']);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_slug_struct', 99);

And here permalinks settings:

Urls seems to be okay, after going to archive to urls are correct, but when I go to single product page I get 404.
What could be the problem or is there other way to have permalink structure I want?
I've tried many plugins but none seems to do what I want

Did you re save permalinks from the settings ? https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-permalinks-screen/
